# Average, between specific date/time, of the difference between current field and previous field

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to calculate the average, between a specific date/time, of the difference between the current field and the previous field. At present I've got a query which displays this but I'm unsure how I can now filter this such that I can get the average of the 'Diff' column between a specific date/time. (Apologies in advance for my sql skill, or lack of.)

```
SELECT 
      S.Pair, 
      S.Date, 
      S.Time, 
      S.Bid, 
      S.Time, 
      ABS(S.Bid - T.Bid) as 'Diff'
FROM 
    dbo.Data as S
CROSS APPLY
           (
            SELECT TOP 1 T.Bid
            FROM
                dbo.Data as T
            WHERE
                 T.Id > S.Id
           ) as T
```

Any pointers would be appreciated.

EDIT:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d4910/1

Comment: Could you perhaps post a load script which includes the Data table's definition and some sample data?  What would also be helpful is a sample result set based on that sample data, showing exactly what you want to see.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I used your SQL Fiddle and [posted a working solution here.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d4910/34)

```
WITH Calc AS
(
    SELECT
        S.Pair,
        S.Date,
        S.Time,
        S.Bid,
        ABS(S.Bid - T.Bid) AS Diff
    FROM dbo.forexData AS S
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT TOP (1)
            T.Bid
        FROM dbo.forexData AS T
        WHERE
            T.Id > S.Id
            AND t.Pair = s.Pair
        ORDER BY
            T.Bid DESC
    ) AS T
)
SELECT
    Pair,
    AVG(DIFF)
FROM Calc
GROUP BY
    Pair;
```

To summarize:

- I fixed a hole in your existing logic - currently your `CROSS APPLY` doesn't link to the same `pair` value so if you have multiple `pair`s then your `DIFF` could be incorrect.
- I put the fixed logic into a `CTE`
- I queried the `CTE` with a `GROUP BY` on `pair`
- I added an `ORDER BY` specification to determine the `TOP` ordering

You can add a date filter in a `WHERE` to the outer `SELECT` if you desire.